# Jquery selector: how to select the element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<h2>
 <a href="exmpale">repeatedtext</a>
</h2>
<p>
</p>
<p> required things    </p>   <--- select this element
```

I have the above sequence of html. The only clue is h2 with a link of text "repeatedtext"

I want to select all the elements show as "select this element" which comes after h2 followed by p

how to do this in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to select element has special text and use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) to select next `p` element

```js
$("h2 > a:contains('repeatedtext')").parent().next("p").next().css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
 <a href="exmpale">repeatedtext</a>
</h2>
<p>text</p>
<p>required things</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `h2:contains(repeatedtext) + p + p`  as the selector

```js
$('h2:contains(repeatedtext) + p + p').css('color', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>
 <a href="exmpale">repeatedtext</a>
</h2>
<p>
</p>
<p> required things    </p>   
<h2>
 <a href="exmpale">not repeated</a>
</h2>
<p>
</p>
<p> not required things    </p>   
<h2>
 <a href="exmpale">repeatedtext</a>
</h2>
<p>
</p>
<p> required things    </p>
```

Comment: h2 with a link which contains repeatedtext. Because the repeatedtext may be contained outside a element

Comment: I don't understand your comment

Comment: @Santhosh Yedidi: That's not at all what your original question suggests. Everything points to the text being *inside* the a element.